# My H2/C3PO/Hibernate setup does not seem to preserving prepared statements?

Tags: database, hibernate, h2, c3p0

I am finding my database is the bottleneck in my application, as part of this it looks like Prepared statements are not being reused.

For example here method I use

```
public static CoverImage findCoverImageBySource(Session session, String src)
{
    try
    {
        Query q = session.createQuery("from CoverImage t1 where t1.source=:source");
        q.setParameter("source", src, StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
        CoverImage result = (CoverImage)q.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But using Yourkit profiler it says

com.mchange.v2.c3po.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatemtn.executeQuery() **Count 511**
com.mchnage.v2.c3po.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement()   **Count 511**

and I assume that the count for prepareStatement() call should be lower, ais it is looks like we create a new prepared statment every time instead of reusing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html

[image]

I am using C3po connecting poolng wehich complicates things a little, but as I understand it I have it configured correctly

public static Configuration getInitializedConfiguration()
{
    //See https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#hibernate-specific
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

```
config.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,"org.h2.Driver");
config.setProperty(Environment.URL,"jdbc:h2:"+Db.DBFOLDER+"/"+Db.DBNAME+";FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=50000");
config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
System.setProperty("h2.bindAddress", InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress());
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","jaikoz");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","jaikoz");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads","10");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","1");
//Consider that if we have lots of busy threads waiting on next stages could we possibly have alot of active
//connections.
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","200");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements","5000");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","2000");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection","50");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period","3000");
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts","10");
//Cancel any connection that is more than 30 minutes old.
//config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout","3000");
//config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
//config.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy", "org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy");
//config.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","true");

config.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics","true");
//config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
//config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
//config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
addEntitiesToConfig(config);
return config;
```

}

Using H2 1.3.172, Hibernate 4.3.11 and the corresponding c3po for that hibernate version

With reproducible test case we have

*HibernateStats*

- HibernateStatistics.getQueryExecutionCount() 28
- HibernateStatistics.getEntityInsertCount() 119
- HibernateStatistics.getEntityUpdateCount() 39
- HibernateStatistics.getPrepareStatementCount() 189

Profiler, method counts

- GooGooStaementCache.aquireStatement() 35
- GooGooStaementCache.checkInStatement() 189
- GooGooStaementCache.checkOutStatement() 189
- NewProxyPreparedStatement.init() 189

I don't know what I shoud be counting as creation of prepared statement rather than reusing an existing prepared statement ?

I also tried enabling c3p0 logging by adding a c3p0 logger ands making it use same log file in my LogProperties but had no effect.

```
            String logFileName = Platform.getPlatformLogFolderInLogfileFormat() + "songkong_debug%u-%g.log";
            FileHandler fe = new FileHandler(logFileName, LOG_SIZE_IN_BYTES, 10, true);
            fe.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            fe.setFormatter(new com.jthink.songkong.logging.LogFormatter());
            fe.setLevel(Level.FINEST);

            MainWindow.logger.addHandler(fe);

            Logger c3p0Logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mchange.v2.c3p0");
            c3p0Logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
            c3p0Logger.addHandler(fe);
```

Comment: a few suggestions: 1) c3p0 dumps its config upon initialization to INFO. if you can find that, verify that the settings you intend are in fact configuring your pool; 2) if you can monitor your pool as a JMX bean, statement cache statistics are reported there in real time; 3) try setting logging to TRACE for `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt` (or more specifically for `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache`) to log what statements are getting checked out and whether there are cache hits.

Comment: Im trying it a different way, Ive commented out all the c3p0 config in HIbernate config. So now no longer c3po and speed is much the same (not faster or slower), main difference is now my main worker threads seem to be busy whereas before they were not doing so much because work was done by C3p0Helper threads, but it still seems to not be reusing Prepared statements. If not using pooling should that allow use of PreparedStaments or would it mean definitently not used because creating a new connection every time.

Comment: @SteveWaldman so that just confirms is using C3P0 (but I cant see how to check all optins are being understood). Okay so I have a test set up and profiler can do method counts so what am I measuring, I will add the stats I do have to question

Comment: @SteveWaldman now added hibernateStatisticCounts and Profiler method counts to the question

Comment: so, from the stats above, it looks like your test is preparing PreparedStatements 189 times, but acquiring them from the database only 35 times. each was reused on average 5.4 times.

Comment: c3p0 tries to log to whatever log library you are using but it has to guess. check your existing logs for a line that begins "MLog clients using" to see what logging library you are using and should configure if you want detailed statement caching logging.

Comment: @SteveWaldman so I was worried initially because calls to prepareStatement() matched number of queries,  but if you are saying that the important things is aquireStatement()

Comment: @SteveWaldan Im just using java.util.logging but I configure all in code

Comment: it’s “transparent statement caching”, clients call prepareStatement as usual each time they want a PreparedStatement, but behind the scenes, if the statement has already been prepared it will be reused. users call prepareStatement on a NewProxyConnection object. behind the scenes, if statement caching is configured, that triggers GooGooStatementCache checkOutStatement(), which triggers acquireStatement (from the db) only if there is a cache miss, if no already-prepared statement is available.

Comment: @SteveWaldman thankyou, okay so the caching of prepared statements is done by C3p0, HIbernate is unaware of the caching. I didn't realize that, but now you say it I use it makes sense. I think what confused me was in another project I only used one connection and I created and cached the prepared statements in teh application itself.

Comment: ha! me too. i used to manually keep Connections and a flock of prepared statements in my applications. but the JDBC3 spec (which c3p0 first implemented, get it "connection pooling 3.0" => c3p0) prescribed transparent pooling of both Connections and Statements (clients use the same API, caching is an implementation detail), and i have to admit it does keep things simpler.

Comment: I did not know that interesting nugget about the name ! If you want to add answer think would be useful to to others and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have eventually got c3p0Based logging working and I can confirm the suggestion of @Stevewaldman is correct.

If you enable

```
public static  Logger  c3p0ConnectionLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt");
c3p0ConnectionLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
c3p0ConnectionLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Then you get log output of the form

```
24/08/2019 10.20.12:BST:FINEST: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.DoubleMaxStatementCache ----> CACHE HIT
24/08/2019 10.20.12:BST:FINEST: checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.DoubleMaxStatementCache stats -- total size: 347; checked out: 1; num connections: 13; num keys: 347
24/08/2019 10.20.12:BST:FINEST: checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.DoubleMaxStatementCache stats -- total size: 347; checked out: 0; num connections: 13; num keys: 347
```

making it clear when you get a cache hit. When there is no cache hit yo dont get the first line, but get the other two lines.

This is using C3p0 9.2.1